# Difficult Cumulative Income Tax Calculation

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets

I've been trying to solve this for days. I can't seem to figure out how to create a one size fits all formula for this cumulative tax.

[image]

I'm trying to achieve the following:

[image]

I can't seem to find a one size fits all solution.

- $8,380.05 = ($55,867.00 - $0.00) * 15.00%
- $11,452.53 = ($111,733.00 - $55,867.00) * 20.50%
- $9,949.42 = ($150,000.00 - $111,733.00) * 26.00% ...

What's the key to this solution? Do I need to just have large amount of "if" statements?

Comment: you can also think about it this way ... 150000 × 15% ... 94133 × 5.5% ... 38267 × 5.5%

Answer (score 1):

This is a case where `MIN` and `MAX` functions can be useful to replace a bunch of `IF` statements. For example, `=MAX(0, A1)` is equivalent to `=IF(A1<0, 0, A1)`.

[image]

To calculate the rate of a given bracket, you need to find the minimum value between `income - min bracket` and `max bracket - min bracket`. If the income is over the maximum value, then the whole bracket will be multiplied to the rate. Otherwise, only the difference between the income and the min bracket.

However, this `MIN()` formula can return a negative value. Therefore, you need to wrap it in a `MAX(MIN(), 0)` to return `0` if the `MIN` gets negative.

I also added an `IF` statement to handle the last and empty maximum bracket. Another way would be to use a maximum bracket of 999,999,999 for instance, but that's less elegant!

```
=C3*MAX(IF(AND(B3<>"", B3<>0), MIN($E$1-A3, B3-A3), $E$1-A3), 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer using multiple if statements:

```
=if($D$2>A3,(if(B3,if(and($D$2>A3,$D$2<B3),$D$2,B3),$D$2)-A3),0)*C3
```

Where `$D$2` is the income cell.